# If $x^2+ax+b$ is an integer for every integer $x$ then comment on the coefficients $a$ and $b$ MCQ

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Probably a more general category (number theory) multiple choice question but no clue how to get to a clear conclusion . Here's how it goes :

> Q)    If  $x^2+ax+b$ is an integer for every integer x then :
> (A)$a$ is always an integer but $b$ need not be an integer
> (B)$b$ is always an integer but $a$ need not be an integer
> (C)$a$ and $b$ are non-integers but a+b should always be an integer
> (D)Both $a$ and $b$ are integers

Please guide me on how to solve this/similar questions.

Thanks.

Comment: The algebraic-number-theory tag seems overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$(x+1)^2+a(x+1)+b=x^2+(2+a)x+1+a+b$$
is an integer and then by subtruction we have
$$(2x+a)$$
is also an integer   and by taking $ x=0$ we see that $a\in \mathbb Z$ and clearly $b$ is an integer by taking $x=0$.

**Added** Simply $x=0$ gives $b$ is an integer and then $x=1$ gives $a$ is also an integer.